# Why do I have to type the ":80" in https://localhost:80 for my website to load?

Tags: node.js, https

I recently secured my website on node.js to use https instead of just plain http. However, once I did this, I realized that I had to type out the :80 suffix if I wanted to get to my website to load. Why is this? Doesn't chrome default to port 80 and shouldn't https://localhost suffice?

````
const port = 80;

https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./private/ssl/server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./private/ssl/server.cert')
}, app)
    .listen(port, function () {
        console.log('Server running on port: ' + port);
    });

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, './') });
});

app.use(express.static('./public'));```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that HTTPS uses port 443 by default, and that's probably the source of your confusion.

If you specify both `https` and `:80` in your browser's address bar, you are making an HTTPS request to port 80, which is unusual.
What kind of reply you will be getting depends on your server's configuration.

Comment: yes, I see that now, thank you, I'll accept a response as the answer once the 10 minute cooldown period is up

Answer (score 3):

The default port for HTTPS is 443, not 80.